# Is there any recent cryptographic algorithm especially designed for low-level processors?

Tags: encryption

Most modern algorithms require relatively large amount of resources.
Is there any recent (and freely usable) encryption/decryption algorithm which is specially designed for low-level microcontrollers in mind? This means it has to run fast, (on a very simple, 8 or 16 bit, 10-20 MHz processor), be small (few hundred bytes to few kilobytes) and use as little RAM as possible.

The key is "modern" because if I took something designed in the 1970's (which would satisfy the requirements for a simple and low-level processor) it might have big security vulnerabilities.

If only the decryption part satisfies the requirements, it's also enough.

Comment: What kind of algorithm do you need? Symmetric encryption? a hash function? key-exchange? signatures? MAC? Authenticated encryption?

Comment: It doesn't have to be symmetric. I intend to have a PC program send a file to a microcontroller, but the user of that PC program should not be able to access the data in that file or edit its contents in a meaningful way. I intend to place the decryption part into the microcontroller, to deny the possibility to read the data by tapping the wire between it and the PC.

Comment: Where does the plaintext come from? Does it get generated by the PC program?

Comment: No. The plaintext is generated at a time and place inaccessible to the user of the PC program, so it can be released already encrypted.

Comment: Does the plaintext need to be authenticated? $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer: not necessarily.

Comment: Then the kind of algorithm you need is either symmetric encryption or authenticated encryption.

Comment: @RickyDemer: Why? It's not important for me to have the same key for encryption/decryption, neither do I wish to identify the source of the file. I just want to provide a file that the PC program can send to the microcontroller, without the user being able to understand its content. The file, the PC program and the mincrocontroller are all provided by me, not necessarily in the same package.

Comment: Using different keys for encryption/decryption would require a bigger decryption key and require more gates to implement. $\:$ (As far as I can find, both of those are by roughly a factor of 2.) $\:$ Hmm..., for symmetric encryption vs. PKE, I have another question: Based on the value of the data, how secure (against the user) you can make the microcontroller, and how many of those you will make, would it make sense for someone to try to steal a secret key database from you? $\;\;$

Comment: @No, it's not a concern. The microcontroller is secured against reading, and the scope of the problem is small enough that I don't need rotating passwords or similar procedures. A single symmetric key will then be sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context, one option would be [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES) in [CTR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode with the XOR between ciphertext and keystream on the PC side (saving most of the bandwidth in the PC to Low-level processor direction). CTR mode allows direct access to any portion of the plaintext. AES is easy to implement on an 8-bit CPU, reasonably fast, and low on resources. As a bonus, protecting AES against side-channel attacks is well studied (although the weakest point likely will be different: obtaining the whole plaintext or keystream once, and storing that).

If AES is not fast enough, and about 260 bytes of RAM are available, and the plaintext can be divided into relatively large blocks (like 1024 bytes or more), and we replace *recent* by *tried and tested*, there is [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) with an appropriate key setup (e.g. append 32-byte key to 8-byte block address, use that as the RC4 key, discard the first 256 bytes produced by RC4).

Update: beware that both methods allow the user to change bits of plaintext just by flipping the corresponding bits of ciphertext; see that [other answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3283/555) if the integrity of plaintext is required (this also requires assuming the program on the PC is not altered).

Comment: Concerning the "recent algorithm" aspect, [ChaCha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#ChaCha20_adoption) seems to be a growing alternative to RC4 suitable for embedded devices.

Answer (score 5):

In the comments, you write:

> "I intend to have a PC program send a file to a microcontroller, but the user of that PC program should not be able to access the data in that file or edit its contents in a meaningful way. I intend to place the decryption part into the microcontroller, to deny the possibility to read the data by tapping the wire between it and the PC."

To accomplish that, what you want is an [authenticated encryption (AE) scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), which is a type of symmetric encryption scheme that also protects the message against modification.  To implement such a scheme, you basically have two options:

1. use a purpose-built AE scheme such as [OCB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCB_mode), [EAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EAX_mode) or [GCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), or
2. combine a [standard non-authenticated block cipher mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) such as CBC or CTR (or a [stream cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher)) with a [message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) using the *Encrypt-then-MAC* construction.

In either case, you will typically need a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) such as [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) as the fundamental building block upon which these schemes are based.  (This is not strictly true — for instance, you could combine a dedicated stream cipher like [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) or [Trivium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium_(cipher)) with a non-cipher-based MAC such as [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) — but most AE schemes are indeed based at least partially on block ciphers.)

As fgrieu notes, AES is a good choice for a block cipher: it's modern, extensively studied, pretty well suited for the task, and it's very likely that a secure implementation of it already exists for your microcontroller.  Besides, AES is as close to the universally accepted standard cipher as there currently is: [nobody's going to get fired for using AES](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/477).