# Why is CAMELLIA suddenly so widely used?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, tls, camellia

When nowadays I point my browser to https sites, the cipher that is on most occasions used is [Camellia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camellia_%28cipher%29). My browsers (Chrome and Firefox) seem to prefer it, even when AES is available.

Is that not kind of dangerous? Camellia did not receive so much scrutiny as did e.g. AES, so we know actually less about its security. Would it not be much better if AES was the default? I know I can change the cipher on Firefox, but it is not obvious how to do the same in Chrome.

Comment: Personally - I've never seen Camellia in use in the wild.  Could you post some links to sites which use it? (I'm curious). RC4 or AES seem to be the most common SSL algorithms these days.  There's some discussion of Camellia [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/476/why-does-nobody-use-or-break-the-camellia-cipher).

Comment: @hunter: login.yahoo.com for one

Comment: @Jumbogram - yes, Yahoo is mentioned in the link that I posted.  Still, that's the only one that I'm aware of. I certainly wouldn't say that Camellia is "widely used" (despite being a strong algorithm).

Comment: This is an example: https://ebanking.easybank.at
As is almost any other austrian bank.

Comment: I just found out that Camellia is a EU recomended cipher: https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/nessie/deliverables/press_release_feb27.pdf
So I guess it was kind of unfair to term it 'dangerous'. Sorry.

Comment: Not sure why you guys say those website use camellia. as far as i can see it uses AES encryption algorithm. ? :S

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason why you see that is because Camellia is the highest-preference cipher in NSS (Chrome and Firefox).  Servers that support Camellia and use the client-preferred cipher suite will use Camellia.

[NSS's rationale for this ordering](https://bug430875.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=319703) is:

> National ciphers such as Camellia are listed before international
>   ciphers such as AES and RC4 to allow servers that prefer Camellia
>   to be able to negotiate Camellia without having to disable AES
>   and RC4, which are needed for interoperability with clients that
>   don't yet implement Camellia.

See also: [Bug 430875](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=430875)

Comment: "reason for NSS's ordering" makes little sense. A server preferring unusual ciphers can simply choose a cipher that's lower on the client's list.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Indeed, this seems like a silly reason, given the existence of [SSLHonorCipherOrder](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslhonorcipherorder) and similar options for other servers. Still, +1 to Jumbogram for figuring out the reason, even if it's silly.